# Doubt about product of four-vectors and Minkowski metric

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, vectors, tensor-calculus, notation

Given the Minkowski metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$

And $\eta^{\mu\nu}\eta_{\mu\nu}$=4

I can write $\eta^{\mu\nu}\eta_{\mu\nu}k^{\mu}k^{\nu}$=$4k^{\mu}k^{\nu}$

But $\eta^{\mu\nu}\eta_{\mu\nu}k^{\mu}k^{\nu}$=$\eta^{\mu\nu}k^{\mu}k_{\mu}$=$\eta^{\mu\nu}k^2$

So $4k^{\mu}k^{\nu}$=$\eta^{\mu\nu}k^2$?

This doesn't seem right. The right side would be zero for $\mu\neq\nu$ but the left side not, in general. But I'm not sure where it is wrong.

(For context, I ran into this while calculating the photon self-energy in qed)

Comment: Your incorrect index structure is misleading you. All repeated indices should be one up and one down. Your second equation should be $\eta^{\mu\nu} \eta_{\mu\nu} k^\alpha k^\beta = 4 k^\alpha k^\beta$. Let me add that if you’re having trouble with manipulating indices like this, you are certainly not ready to compute the photon self-energy. That’s not a problem, of course! But you should go back to the beginning and strengthen your foundations first before attempting the more difficult calculations.

Comment: I put the context because I've seen notes replacing $k^{\mu}k^{\nu}$ for $k^2$ inside the momentum integral that way and I wondered why it was not valid in general. But yes, I'm still bad with index notation

Comment: you can do this replacement inside momentum integrals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indices must always come in pairs or singles, never more than two. And when they come in pairs one must be up and the other down. Your equation violates this rule so it has an ill-formed expression on the left hand side: $$\eta^{\mu\nu}\eta_{\mu\nu}k^{\mu}k^{\nu} $$ is ambiguous. It could either be: $$\eta^{\mu\nu}\eta_{\mu\nu}k^{\alpha}k^{\beta} = 4k^{\alpha}k^{\beta}$$ or it could be $$\eta^{\alpha\beta}\eta_{\mu\nu}k^{\mu}k^{\nu} = \eta^{\alpha\beta}k^2$$ or it could even be $$\eta^{\alpha\nu}\eta_{\mu\nu}k^{\mu}k^{\beta} = k^{\alpha}k^{\beta}$$

Those are all three different equations. They are not generally equal to each other.